# prove a bondle is an indefinite Hermitian manifold which is Kahler if and only if the manifold is locally flat

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, manifolds, kahler-manifolds

Let $M(J,g)$ be an indefinite Kahler manifold, then $%
TM(J^{H},g^{D})$ is an indefinite Hermitian manifold which is Kahler if and
only if $M$ is locally flat. Here $J^{H}$ denotes the horizontallift of $J$ and $g^{D}$ is the sasaki metric

Comment: You might want to try asking this question, and your other questions, at math.stackexchange first, before asking them here, unless you are certain that they are open research problems, or otherwise unsuitable for math.stackexchange. To me, this looks like it could perhaps be an exercise from a graduate level textbook. Why do you think it is an open research problem?

Comment: you're right, I should probably post it on math.stackexchange first

Comment: Add a comment with a link, when you do ask it there.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3671933/prove-a-bondle-is-an-indefinite-hermitian-manifold-which-is-kahler-if-and-only-i